# Writing/reading in to binary/text files

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2013, text-files, binaryfiles

```
wFile.open(fileName, ios::out | ios::trunc);
if (!(wFile.is_open()))
{
    cout << "Error in opening the file" << endl;
    return false;
}
else
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Widgets.size(); i++)
    {
        Widgets.at(i)->copyToBinary(fileName);
    }
    wFile.close();
    return true;
}
```

I'm trying to copy different objects types from a vector. My problem is that when this code runs for the copy, it only copies the last object. It seems like the code just overrides the existing text.

Also, I have this code in each class (this is the copyToBinary function):

```
ofstream file(fName);
file << *this;
file << endl;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Surely using the text stream operators of `<<` can't be right for writing data to a binary file?

Comment: I do believe so that i can not use standard << operator to copy data from objects sense binary files contains Chars

Comment: Obviously, a binary file is a file that can contain text, so it is possible, but if you do that with, say, the type `int`, it will write 12345, not the binary representation of 12345 (0x00003039 - in the correct byte order). Likewise, if your operator `<<` for some object is used for `cout`, you expect to get a text representation, so it is not customary to use `<<` to write to binary files.

Comment: Then what will be the "safest" way to do so? i mean what are my other options other then file.write()

Comment: seems like useing this : file.write((char*)this, sizeof(obj)); is working well so far, so i guess this would be my answer

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't have pointers (including, but far from limited to, vtables) in the object, you should be fine doing that. If you have pointers, you will need to serialize out the data.

Comment: We haven't got to serialization yet go i believe this would not be a problem in this case :)

Comment: Obviously, without knowing your education schedule, it's pretty hard to know what you "have got to" and what you haven't. And you haven't included the actual class declaration.

Comment: My apologies but i have 12 classes so including them here wont be a good idea i think , as long as the code works i will not try and fix it heh, at this point i will continue to the next stage and to try and load the info from file , wish me luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

You pass the finename to `copyToBinary()`, reopening a stream and overwriting it.

**Solution:**

Pass the wFile stream as reference and write to it without reopening each time

```
void copyToBinary(ostream& file) {
   file << *this;
   file << endl;
}
```

Comment: I bilive that if i would like to save it as a binary file then insted of useiong the  "file << *this;" i will need to use the file.write((char*))this,sizeof(object))?

Comment: If you use `file.write`, watch out for pointers and other "indirect data".

Comment: will it affect me if my data sotored in a : vector < Widget *>

Comment: vector is not a problem, because you call the function for one specific instance.  But if you'd like to write binary, don't forget to open wFile with `ios::binary` !

Answer (score 0):

You should not reopen the file in `copyToBinary`. Pass `wFile` as argument not `filename` :

```
...copyToBinary(ostream &file) {
  file << *this;
  file << endl;
}
```

and call `...copyToBinary(wFile)`.

Comment: what causes it to re-open? "file" is a ofstream type... and if i pass it by argument how will the function will know to what file to write to?

Comment: `ofstream file(filename)` opens the file!

Comment: thanks Jean im still new to c++ im just finshed my first year in collage i have a lot to learn :)\

Answer (score 0):

First, when you are opening the file

```
wFile.open(fileName, ios::out | ios::trunc);
```

Everytime it is called the existing content get lost as you are using `trunc` mode. It will be better if you use `ios::app` mode. So that whenever the above code runs, it opens the file in append mode.

Second, You are passing the filename in the `copyToBinary` function. And By using the default constructor

```
ofstream file(fName);
```

your file is getting opened everytime in default `ios::out` mode but not in `ios::app` mode. It will be better either you pass the refernece of opened file or open the file in function as append mode.

Comment: so in general you say to remove the ios::trunc?

Comment: If you want to retain the data in the file when you run your program again then yes.

Comment: Yes i do need to load back that data in the file after i save it, so yes i do need to remove ios::trunc